# VB + ASP + MySQL: how to know if I have idle opened connections to mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic, connection-pooling

The situation:

- I have a website on a Windows web hosting
- It uses both VBScript + classic ASP both VB .NET + ASP .NET
- It has thousands of code pages (in part written by me, in part by others)

The problem:

- I have a lot of connections that remains opened in an "idle" state
- These connections force the site to rapidly reach the limit of simultaneous connections to the MySQL DB
- The reach of connection limit means to put offline my website
- Obviously, I cannot change the limit of connections on the server (and it is not a good idea)

The questions:

- How can I find the badly written code where connections are opened and not closed (considering that the problem happens only online)?

Thanks in advance to all will reply to help me to solve this big big problem.

Comment: "How can I find the badly written code where connections are opened and not closed (considering that the problem happens only online)?" You need to go manually through your source code no other option.

Comment: clean up your code when you're finish. Make a meeting and get changes asap. this is bad practice. if you're all using the same class to access the DB it shouldn't be hard to figure out

Comment: Since I can see the idle connections, there is no way to recognize / label the source (the file where it happens)?

Comment: MySQL by default has a very high value for the [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) system variable. If connections are not properly closed, a connection will be in a sleeping state until it eventually times out; which by default is 8 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to identify these connections location, the best you could do is inspect what sql is being executed and then match that sql with where it's being executed in your code pages. Not easy, but it could be a good starting point.

if you generally use the same variable names for your recordset / connections, you could check for it's existence by using the isObject() function, then checking it's state to see if it's open, then do your clean up work from there, so something like:

```
classic asp code

function cleanUp( obj )
    if isObject( obj ) then
        if obj.State <> 0 then obj.Close      '-- check to see if the connection is open, if so, close it'
        set obj = nothing
    end if
end function
```

if you have an include file that is on every page (like maybe a footer), you can stick this in there and call it on different variables you may have used:

```
cleanUp( rs )
cleanUp( rsUsers )
cleanUp( rsProfiles )
cleanUp( myConnectionObject )
```

even if you don't use that particular variable name in a specific file, it won't fail because of the isObject() check.

This would be the first approach I would take, as it'll give me some immediate relief. However, this would equivalent to a band-aid, you still need to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: I am trying... sleeping connections may also appear for too long queries?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sleeping connections", but yes, queries that take longer to execute will def cause distress against your database, impacting performance.